# I want close the splash screen in JavaFx. But It is not closing instead the 2nd the window is opening

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I have 2 FXML pages. when home page running as splash screen showing then I need to auto close the splash screen and isteead of that I want to open the Dashboard . But here it is not  close the splash screen in JavaFx  instead the 2nd the window is opening and in the background the splash screen is still showing there.I tried some ways but it is not working.

Following is the code for splash screen home page . Design in FXML and coding doing in Netbeans 12.

```
package abc123;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HomeController implements Initializable {
 
    private AnchorPane rootpane ;
    
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pane;
    
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     splash();
    }    
    private void splash() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(""+e);
                }
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try {
                            rootpane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Maindash.fxml"));
                            Stage stage = new Stage();
                           
                            Scene scene = new Scene(rootpane);
                            //pane.setVisible(false);
                            stage.setTitle("Dash");
                            stage.setScene(scene);
                            stage.show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        
                    }
                });
                 
            }
        }.start();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Where are you closing the current stage?

Comment: [mcve] please .. und put a bit of effort into code formatting to make it easily readable

Comment: @James_D that is main prblm where I can set the  closing code..

Comment: Surely you want to close the original window exactly when you show the new one (in the `Platform.runLater()` runnable).

Comment: @James_D Is this below the ' stage,show() ' ??

Comment: Yes, or before it; it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @James_D Can u make an answer in answer comment?

Comment: How can I answer? I don't even know what the problem is. Just hide the window.

Comment: @James_D it is showing as an error..

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the current window when you open the new one.

```
private void splash() {
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        rootpane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Maindash.fxml"));
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                       
                        Scene scene = new Scene(rootpane);
                        stage.setTitle("Dash");
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();

                        // hide current window:
                        pane.getScene().getWindow().hide();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                }
            });
             
        }
    }.start();
    
    
}
```